# Ruby Text Parsing: Find the start of the next sentence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, text, string-parsing

I have a bunch of strings in my database like this:

> driving home from work. The dog leaped of the sofa to great his
>   master at the door. He licked his face clean.

The strings start off in the middle of a sentence. I'd like figure a way to cut off the initial incomplete sentence and just return from "The dog leaped of the sofa to great his master at the door. He licked his face clean."

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how to define incomplete sentence. We can make an assumption that all sentences which begins with upcased character is complete sentences. If so code may look like this

```
str = 'driving home from work. The dog leaped of the sofa to great his master at the door. He licked his face clean.'
sentences = str.split('.')
sentences.shift if sentences[0][0].downcase == sentences[0][0]
sentences.join('.').strip << '.'
```

A little bit tricky but works.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest possible answer:

```
str = 'driving home from work. The dog leaped of the sofa to great his master at the door. He licked his face clean.'
str.sub!(/^[^A-Z].+?\./, '').strip!
```

Comment: This will remove first sentence regardless ... and leaves a blank behind.

Comment: Now fixed. Will remove only if text not begins with uppercase to the next dot. Also `strip!` will remove all beginnin and following whitespaces.

Comment: I like it, simple, easy to remember. And it takes care of cases where first sentence starts with digits, symbols, etc.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ged/linkparser

This may help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
str = "driving home from work. The dog leaped of the sofa to great his master at the door. He licked his face clean."
str.first == str.first.upcase ? str : str.split(".")[1..-1].join(".").lstrip << "."
```

Assuming that the fact that it start with an upper letter indicates the beginning of a sentence, otherwise it is not possible. Other case to consider, what if it starts with numeric? Ex: 1 dog ran away. The dog ... is 1 Dog ... a sentence?